# Zip 'ing an Export Data's From JSP Page to Multiple Excel Sheets Both at same time (Export+ ZIP) in JAVA / JSP

Tags: java, export-to-excel, zip

In my Project i Have to Export Table Data's from many pages and export all the page as different sheets in a same Excel Document ...when Export to Excel button is clicked in each page the corresponding sheet is updated The excel document is same Export2Excel.xls

I  have some how acomplished this task ...But?

They have now asked to zip the  same file  Export2Excel.xls after zipping it they said to reduce size of the Excel sheet...the catch is I have to create the excel file and create zip file both at the same click of button (Export to Excel)..

What to Do ...?
S.O.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not first create/update the excel file and create the zip afterwards? Just do it in the same servlet/backend method and use a defined name for the zip. Shouldn't be too hard. If you have to return the file I'd return the zip.